# Always getting error code 400(bad request) on requesting tweet detail via twitter sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter

Below is the code for main activity

```
**public class TwitterMain extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout myLayout;
    private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tweet_layout);
        //find the id of main layout
        mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        //find id of TweetView
        TweetView tweetView = (TweetView)findViewById(R.id.tweet_view);
        //set callback action to TweetView to listen favorite event
        tweetView.setOnActionCallback(actionCallback);
        //find id of CompactTweetView
        CompactTweetView compactTweetView = (CompactTweetView)findViewById(R.id.compact_tweet_view);
        //set callback action to CompactTweetView to listen favorite event
        compactTweetView.setOnActionCallback(actionCallback);
        //load runtime Tweet
        loadTweet();
    }
    private void loadTweet() {
        //use any TweetID
        final long tweetId = 952933941702545408L;
        //start loading tweet and pass TweetID
        TweetUtils.loadTweet(tweetId, new Callback<Tweet>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
                //create TweetView or CompactTweetView with "result.data"
                final TweetView tweetView = new TweetView(TwitterMain.this, result.data,
                        R.style.tw__TweetDarkWithActionsStyle);
                //set action callback
                tweetView.setOnActionCallback(actionCallback);
                //finally add created Tweet to LinearLayout
                mainLayout.addView(tweetView);
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                //show toast if some exception occurs
                Toast.makeText(TwitterMain.this, "Failed to show Tweet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    // launch the login activity when a guest user tries to favorite a Tweet
    final Callback<Tweet> actionCallback = new Callback<Tweet>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Tweet> result) {
            // Intentionally blank
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            if (exception instanceof TwitterAuthException) {
                Toast.makeText(TwitterMain.this, "User is guest.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //launch login activity from here
                //ask user to login
            }
        }
    };
}**
```

code for adding config for twitter in application class--

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(*************", "**********************************"))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);
```

below is the xml for main activity-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tweet view"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <!-- TweetView with Dark Style theme, here pass any Tweet Id in
         place of tw__tweet_id  -->
        <com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetView
            android:id="@+id/tweet_view"
            style="@style/tw__TweetDarkWithActionsStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tw__tweet_id="954329648879587328" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Compact tweet view"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <!-- CompactTweetView with Light Style theme, here pass any
        Tweet Id in place of tw__tweet_id  -->
        <com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.CompactTweetView
            android:id="@+id/compact_tweet_view"
            style="@style/tw__TweetLightWithActionsStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tw__tweet_id="953599133318819843" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="tweet view runtim"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <!--  Here the runtime Tweet will be shown and will be added in runtime -->


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Note--always getting error code 400 from twitter sdk, if anyone can kindly help.looks like some authorisation error for consumer key and secret key , but i am passing them correctly and also tried generating new key, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Hello, Can you state your end goal here. Are you trying to display a single tweet of a user or all the tweets from  a user? I had implemented loading a User's timeline ie. all tweets he/she may have. If you are trying to do the same, I might be of some help. Twitter SDK is a pain in the ass though.

Comment: yes i want to display a single tweet. actually the main goal is to play twitter native video, which is not working  when used with iframes in webview. so i was trying to do this with twitter sdk

Comment: I just checked my implementation and it has all the tweets (not a single tweet) from a user and the videos posted on the user's timeline do play without leaving my app.

Comment: are you using twitter sdk? if yes, can you share the code with me because i am not able to understand why error is coming

Comment: i think if you are able to display the complete timeline then we can tweak it to display single tweet based on twitterId.

Comment: I do not quite know that. It's been a long since I have had to work on twitter. However the code to get display timeline is: [here](https://github.com/HemrajRijal/SajhaParty/blob/master/app/src/main/java/fragments/TwitterFragment.java)

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Oh sorry it was a private github repo, I'll pastebin and share. [here](https://pastebin.com/QCV6hD9b) and the xml is [here](https://pastebin.com/Yn1xJZ2d)

Comment: Also have a look at [this](https://httpstatuses.com/400) for 400 error.

Comment: did u keep keys in the string file ?

Comment: I actually created a `twitter.properties` file and loaded it from the gradle script. But you can do it anyway. String file, java class or anything that is good for you. Just make sure you do not push the keys to public git repo